# Arangodb Java Driver, how to update edges with additional info

Tags: java, driver, arangodb, edges

im trying to write an application in java with arangodb as my database. I need to use graphs, creating/updating nodes worked quite well, but now im stuck with edges. I already found a post here, that told me how to create edges with additional info:

```
    EdgeEntity<?> edge = ArangoDriver.graphCreateEdge( graphName, collectionName, null, sorceHandler, destinationHandler, new Postions(x, y), null);
```

This is working as well, but what i need to do now, is to get that info from the edge again to update it. For example i want to increase both of those coordinates in Positions(x,y) by 5. In base documents id try ".getProperties()" but how can i do the same with edges?

Comment: Not being a java expert, but, maybe https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb-java-driver/blob/master/src/test/java/com/arangodb/ArangoDriverGraphEdgeUpdateTest.java can give valuable information?

Comment: Thanks, that helped alot!

Answer (score 1):

We recently added Java examples [to the driver sourcecode](https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb-java-driver/#learn-more). Most of these samples resemble parts of [the documentation where they were implemented in Javascript](http://docs.arangodb.com)